# Does using a HAML instead of an HTML file with Jquery change the inputs of the onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, haml

I have a haml file and a button with an id. Does this change the inputs of the on click function. The traditional method for using on click is not working. What changes need to be made?

```
.chatboxhead
  .chatboxtitle
    %i.fa.fa-comments
    %h1
      = @reciever.uname
    %button.interview.full{:id => "button_reg"} 申し込み
  .chatboxoptions
    = link_to "<i class='fa  fa-minus'></i> ".html_safe, "#", class: "toggleChatBox", "data-cid" => @conversation.id
      
    \#{link_to "<i class='fa  fa-times'></i> ".html_safe, "#", class: "closeChat", "data-cid" => @conversation.id}
  %br{:clear => "all"}/
```

My JQuery is below:

```
//opens a form on button click
openform: function() {
    $('#button_reg').click(function () {
        console.log("Testing Click");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this has no effect. HAML is rendered to HTML for rendering in the browser; Jquery operates on this rendered HTML, not on the HAML.

I don't think your event is wired up the way you expect. You're registering the click handler in the openform event, which means that it's not active until after the form opens. If you're expecting it to *open* the form, it won't work.